# Extract allele specific information from dataframe using regex and split this into two new dataframes

Tags: r, regex, bash, dataframe, split

I have a 100 by 100 dataframe, which contains 100 sample IDs for 100 SNPs in the genome, in the following format.

```
structure(list(`c("12545=1", "12545=0")` = c("12545=1|1", "12545=0|0"
), `c("12994=0|0", "12994=0|1")` = c("12994=0|0", "12994=0|1"
), `c("15240=0|0", "15240=1|1")` = c("15240=0|0", "15240=1|1"
)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

The integers at either side of the `|` represent the genotype of each individual. I'm looking for a solution in bash or R, potentially using regex, that creates two new data frames each with the same dimensions as the first. One dataframe containing only the reference allele info for each sample at each locus, so containing only the integer value before the `|` and the second dataframe containing the alternate allele info at each locus, i.e. only the value of the integer after the `|` in each cell. Thus, two new 100 x 100 dataframes of 1s and 0s would be generated.

Everything before the `=` can be disregarded.

Any advice on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you share a part of your data using `dput()`?

Comment: I have edited the question. I wasn't aware of the dput() function. Very useful. Many Thanks Bas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data is stored in a data frame `df`, this should do what you want:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- df %>% 
  mutate_all(~ str_extract(., "\\d(?=\\|)"))

df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate_all(~ str_extract(., "(?<=\\|)\\d"))


df1

#   `c("12545=1", "12545=0")` `c("12994=0|0", "12994=0|1")` `c("15240=0|0", "15240=1|1")`
#   <chr>                     <chr>                         <chr>                        
# 1 1                         0                             0                            
# 2 0                         0                             1                            


df2

#   `c("12545=1", "12545=0")` `c("12994=0|0", "12994=0|1")` `c("15240=0|0", # "15240=1|1")`
#   <chr>                     <chr>                         <chr>                        
# 1 1                         0                             0                            
# 2 0                         1                             1
```

Note that the column names in your example are a bit weird, but it should work nonetheless.